# How can I shift columns of tibbles in a nested tibble?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have a data frame with lot of categories. For a category I calculate a shifting value. With this value I want to shift every column of this part of the data frame downwards by this value. To perform this I thought it might be useful to use a "nested tibble" and then use a `map` function of `purrr` to perform the shifting.

To artificially reproduce the problem, I would create such a data frame with the iris data set:

```
df <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest() %>% mutate(shift = as.integer(c(1, 2, 3)))

df

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data              shift
  <fct>      <list>            <int>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>     1
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>     2
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>     3
```

My intention was to use a map function which takes every column of the tibbles in "data" and shift them by the shift values. In code (it is not running, just for clarification:

```
df %>% mutate(data.shift = map(data, lag(.x, n = shift)))
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    data              shift    data.shift
  <fct>      <list>            <int>    <list>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]>     1    <tibble[50 x 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]>     2    <tibble[50 x 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]>     3    <tibble[50 x 4]>
```

where every column of "data.shift" has a lag of value shift. For example for the first row the unnested tibble would look like:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 4
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1        NA          NA           NA         NA    
 2         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200
 3         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200
 4         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200
 5         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200
 6         5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200
 7         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400
 8         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300
 9         5.00        3.40         1.50       0.200
10         4.40        2.90         1.40       0.200
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Is there a way to perform this using the `purrr::map` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also do this without anonymous call, if we specify the parameter name

```
df %>% 
    mutate(data.shift = map2(data, shift, ~ .x %>% 
                                               mutate_all(lag, n = .y)))
```

---

Or using `data.table` `shift` that can take data.table or data.frame to shift

```
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   mutate(data.shift = map2(data, shift, ~  
          as.data.table(.x)[, (names(.x)) := shift(.SD, n = .y)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

```
df %>% mutate(data.shift = map2(data, shift, ~mutate_all(.x, function(z) lag(z, .y)))
```